# Firebase database rules. Unable to write data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am new to firebase rules. And I am not able to write data to user node who is currently logged in.
My db structure is,

```
userdata: {
  profile: {
    Lp6Sj763bVUXlisPJyaLM3gbns73: {
      name: "sample"
      avatar: "sample.png",
      userid: "albdchalwe"
    },
    FRw6J6GWK6YbvhuaaHNzPtLRSHJ2: {
      name: "sample"
      avatar: "sample.png",
      userid: "calisdnca"
    }
  },
  additionaldata: {
    Lp6Sj763bVUXlisPJyaLM3gbns73: {
      notifications: {
        0: {
          notificationId: "cbawln"
          receviedon: 12212
        },
        1: {
          notificationId: "cbawln"
          receviedon: 12212
        }
      }
    },
    FRw6J6GWK6YbvhuaaHNzPtLRSHJ2: {
      notifications: {
        0: {
          notificationId: "cbawln"
          receviedon: 12212
        },
        1: {
          notificationId: "cbawln"
          receviedon: 12212
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And wanted to give write access to node which is related to currently logged in user. My database rules are,

```
{
  rules: {
    userdata: {
     profile: {
       .read: "auth != null",
       .indexOn: ["name"]
       $userId: {
         avatar: {
           .write: "$userId == auth.uid"
         },
         avatar: {
           .write: "$userId == auth.uid"
         }
         userid: {
           .write: "$userId == auth.uid && !data.exists()"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

user node under profile contains more nodes. I just added 3 sub nodes fro user node to understand the structure. Leave the additionaldata node for now.

My problem is unable write the data to profile node. When I run it on simulator, I am getting the following,

[[image]

[image][image]

Can anyone help me fixing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check if you can write just a string value `sample.png` to path `/userdata/profile/myuid` when you set UID to `myuid`?

Comment: Sorry for the late @FrankvanPuffelen, No, I couldn't.

Comment: Hmmm... that sounds unexpected with your rules. Can you update your question to show the screenshot(s) for that?

Comment: I think @Tony's edited answer is right. But I have around 20 sub nodes under user node. So how can save each key like `db.object('userdata/profile/'+userId+'/avatar').set('sample.png')`. Currently my implementation is, `db.object('userdata/profile/'+userId).set({avatar:'sample.png', email:'sampl@sample.com'})`, This is just example, there are so many keys. I can't define exact path for each and every entry.

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you are writing to `/userdata/profile/$uid` instead of `/userdata/profile/$uid/avatar` where the `.write` is defined? (It is also duplicated in your example)

Comment: I have tried all these, `$uid, $user_id, $userId`. No use.

Comment: As per the firebase docs, Shallower security rules override rules at deeper paths. See here, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data. `.write` also does the same. If I add it to top level node, it applies to child nodes well.

Comment: Edited again @HarinKommuri